# Создание объекта класса в Android

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста , что как называется этот прием.

```
 Toast.makeText(this, "My text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

И как он работает . Насколько я понимаю здесь неявно создается объект класса Toast . Мы не используем оператор new так как объект создается с помощью метода makeText ? Почему именно так ? И почему не используют обычный конструктор .

> Toast myToast = new Toast()

` .
Объясните пожалуйста почему так делается и как это работает . 
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 5):

В подобных случаях рекомендую всегда смотреть сорцы, тем более, что они доступны:

’./sources/android-19/android/widget/Toast.java’

```
public static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) {
    Toast result = new Toast(context);

    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflate.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.transient_notification, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.message);
    tv.setText(text);

    result.mNextView = v;
    result.mDuration = duration;

    return result;
}
```

Здесь хорошо видно, как создается объект, настраивается и возвращается готовый объект. То есть, формально makeText является конструктором.

Comment: Скорее фабрикой.

Answer (score 3):

По сути такое создание объекта (как в данном случае через вызов статического метода) называется [паттерном Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Суть паттерна фабрика состоит в том, что иногда создание объекта сопряжено с трудностями, например объект создать несложно, но правильная его инициализация может быть довольно сложной и запутанной. В таких случаях рекомендуется применение этого паттерна.

В данном случае это неплохо иллюстрируется исходниками показанными [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim). Действительно, сам голенький `Toast` малоинтересен, чтобы он заработал его надо обложить правильным лейаутом и проч. причиндалами - что и делает статический метод `Toast.makeText()`

Answer (score 2):

Статический метод `makeText` создаёт экземпляр класса `Toast`. В чём проблема то?

Answer (score 2):

если кратко то потому что так проще...

если подробно то создавая вручную `Toast myToast = new Toast()` вы можете дополнительно его настроить например отступы и положение

а если создадите класс потомок  то вообще сможете поменять всё...